# Will earth rotation be slowed down?

Tags: energy, angular-momentum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are tidal power plants slowing down Earth's rotation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6400/are-tidal-power-plants-slowing-down-earths-rotation)

Since we have various energy acquiring facilities that harvest energy from earth rotation. (e.g. wind, tidal power planet)

Will our earth rotation be slower down? Is there any form of force to accelerate earth rotation speed?

Comment: Probably the strongest influence here is from the Moon.

Comment: yer, but there is always some amount of resistance to earth rotation. Just wondering that eventually earth might stop rotate...

Comment: This is duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6400/are-tidal-power-plants-slowing-down-earths-rotation

Comment: well im also asking if there is any sort of force to accelerate earth rotation?

Comment: As during ages Earth cools down then probably its radius may shrink slightly...