# The moon affects the motion of the oceans, but can the motion of the oceans affect the moon?

Tags: forces, gravity, earth, moon

Obviously the earth's oceans have mass and therefore they have an attractive force upon the moon.

However, let's say that we were to cover most of earth with tidal power generators that extract some of this energy from the ocean.
Could this affect the moon?

How about if we were to otherwise freeze the earth's oceans, or lock them in with a layer of cement to prevent them from being tidal?

Comment: We already have several question on the site about the tdal energy and angular momentum transfer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=tidal+energy+transfer . Another possible useful search term for the general process is "tidal lock".

Comment: Thank you, I've found this which seems to answer the basis of my query. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6400/are-tidal-power-plants-slowing-down-earths-rotation/6404#6404

Comment: Whatever is in our power is utterly negligible.