# Do we have the potential technology to harness the energy the Earth is constantly giving us?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, velocity, thought-experiment

Messing around with fun physics, and it got me thinking. I probably am not the only or the first one to think of it. I am wondering what more experienced physicists on this site can contribute to this thought experiment.

We are constantly moving because earth is constantly rotating on its axis. Using quick numbers and assuming.. a lot of things. Is there a way, and do we have the technology to harness the energy the earth constantly exerts on us?

I am a 95kg adult, and assuming I am at the equator I have a linear velocity of about 463m/s.

Using the $$v_{linear}=\frac{\Delta x} {\Delta t}= \frac{2 \pi R}{86400s} = \space \sim463\space m/s $$

This gives me a Kinetic energy of $\sim 1.03 \times 10^{7}J$

Spanning over the time period of a day on the earth, I assume, gives me about 118 watts of power per second.

What are some the pros and cons to this thought?

Comment: Just a quick thought, if you remove rotational energy, the length of the day will increase. In fact, the moon is doing this right now as it recedes.

Comment: @tmwilson26: it's just another way of ruining the planet! ;)

Comment: @Gert using the moon as a doomsday device is playing the serious long game. :)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6400/2451 and links therein.